kvm-ok, but dev/kvm not found - emulating android by budtmo repo
I'm having a problem with kvm. Virtualization in Bios is turned on, and kvm-ok is saying that it can be used, but when Im running
docker run -d -p 6080:6080 -e EMULATOR_DEVICE="Samsung Galaxy S10" -e WEB_VNC=true --device /dev/kvm --name android-container budtmo/docker-android:emulator_14.0

I'm occuring error:
docker: Error response from daemon: error gathering device information while adding custom device "/dev/kvm": no such file or directory.

Im using Ubuntu 22.04.04 with dualboot
I'have tried diffrent emualtors from this repo and reinstall docker
